# R purrr, can I use two arrays in a modify_if statement?

Tags: r, arrays, vector, vectorization, purrr

I want to use one array to decide whether or not to modify another, hoping to use modify_if, but there might be a simpler way.  Here is my mwe.

```
vec1 <- array( c(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 3))

vec2 <- array(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))

vec1 %<>% purrr::modify_if(~ .x[vec2], vec1 + 1)
```

So I already have the logical array to tell me which ones to change.  If vec2 is TRUE, then I want to modify the value at that index to increment the current value of vec1 by 1, otherwise if vec2 is false then leave in the original value.  The result I am looking for is 
2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3.  Thx, J.

Comment: Are you looking for `vec1[vec2] <- vec1[vec2] + 1` ?

Answer (score 4):

Within the tidyverse, I think you want

```r
vec1
# [1] 1 3 5 6 7 3 2 3
vec1 %<>% purrr::modify_if(vec2, ~ .x + 1)
vec1
# [1] 2 4 5 7 7 3 3 3
```

Though as @MartinGal suggested, base R's might be more direct:

```r
vec1 <- array( c(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 3))
vec1[vec2] <- vec1[vec2] + 1
vec1
# [1] 2 4 5 7 7 3 3 3
```